# Windows open files dialog with all files + subdirectories

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a program called BulkFileChanger, and when I add files - it opens Windows dialog where I can select files. Now that is common windows dialog and I can select all files ( ctr+a) and it selects all files + all subdirecotires, but when you click OPEN it just imports files, not the files contained in subdirecotires, so is there a way to actually open all files + all files in all subdirectories in normal windows open files dialog ? I am also using some other programs that can open "bulk" files, but strange thing is that none of them (who uses normal windows open files dialog) can actaully open subfolders.... is there some kind of shortcut in Windows that will allow this feature ?

Answer (score 1):

The file dialog will not do this for you. There is no setting that will make it recurse into sub-folders and return all files contained within. If you want that functionality you must implement it yourself.